# Problems with PostgreSQL and ESRI Geoportal Installation on CentOS

Tags: postgresql, centos

I am installing geoportal 1.2.4 on CentOS from the command line terminal...during my installation I am receiving a fatal ident error message for my user geoportal. The pg_hba.conf file has been altered to follow my credentials accordingly, yet I am consistently receivng this error for both the default user postgres and my created user geoportal.

I have created a geoportal db with geoportal user with a password. Trust and md5 authentication methods have been explored in this configuration.  I have also installed the ident server, with no avail.

I am able to connect to the geoportal db as postgres user. Below is a screen shot of the error which is returned for both the postgres and geoportal user.....

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A look at the PostgreSQL user manual would be well advised here, particularly [`pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) and the rest of the [client authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html) chapter.

You're trying to use `ident` authentication but the user ID doesn't match or the `ident` daemon isn't running.

You probably want `md5` password authentication instead.

Comment: That's the problem, the pg_hba.conf file has been edited using md5 authentication methods, but even when connecting it calls the incorrect database and auth methods.

Comment: @GeoffreyWest Did you restart PostgreSQL, `pg_ctl reload ` or `select pg_reload_conf()` afterwards? Please edit the question to show your hba file.

Comment: seems as if the issue involved the postgres.conf file not having the proper permissions.  

chmod -R 0700 /var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data solved this.